# How to interpret standard deviation calculated by excel

Tags: data, visualization, data-analysis, excel

I have some percentage values in my excel spreadsheet like:

[image]

When i use the `STDEV` function to calculate the standard deviation with these values, i get `0,125`. How should i interpret this? Is it `+- 0,125%` or `+-12,50%`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should interpret it as `12.5%`.

The percentage values that you are seeing in your spreadsheet (93.33%, ...) are only formats, internally Excel is dealing with decimal point numbers (.9333, ...) so the result of the standard deviation will be in the same scale: `.125 -> 12.5%`